# SQL updte trigger to add and subtract

Tags: mysql

I have a simple question, but I haven't seen an answer that makes sense to me. I am doing an assignment for school, and the request is for an update trigger. When a line is updated in one table, the count data in another table needs to be subtracted and added. But sql is complaining about my trigger. Do I need the "and" in this code? Or am I just missing the point all together?

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE TRIGGER AlterUpdate AFTER UPDATE
    ON Projects_collier.Assign
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE Project
    SET numEmployeesAssigned = numEmployeesAssigned +1
    WHERE projNO = NEW.projNO
    AND numEmployeesAssigned = numEmployeesAssigned -1
    WHERE projNO = OLD projNO;
    END$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two `WHERE` clauses in an `UPDATE` statement.  But you can rephrase your `UPDATE` using a `CASE` expression to have the logic you want:

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE TRIGGER AlterUpdate AFTER UPDATE
    ON Projects_collier.Assign FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE Project
    SET
        numEmployeesAssigned = CASE WHEN projNO = NEW.projNO
                                    THEN numEmployeesAssigned + 1
                                    WHEN projNO = OLD.projNO
                                    THEN numEmployeesAssigned - 1 END
    WHERE
        projNO IN (NEW.projNO, OLD.projNO)
END$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Okay. This makes sense. I'll try it out. Thanks!